# page layout design usng bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create standard responsive page using bootstrap css. Just created simple page with header, page content and side links. I have few doubts here.

1. I put 4% margin for all 4 side, but even why top and botton margin less compare to left right?
2. Why there is much distance between well and page-header?
3. I took hr for link seperation, why it is taking so much distance between each?
4. Can I set all border color to #27ae60

Link to fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/EjFjr/1/

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row clearfix">

        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div class="well">
                Welcome ...! 
                Get you timeline info ...
            </div>

            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>
                    <small>Get purified for all desease</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:75%" valign= "top">
                        <p> Triaenops menamena is a bat in the genus Triaenops found on Madagascar, mainly in the drier regions. It was known as Triaenops rufus until 2009, when it was discovered that that name had been incorrectly applied to the species. Triaenops rufus is a synonym of Triaenops persicus, a closely related Middle Eastern species. Triaenops menamena is mostly found in forests, but also occurs in other habitats. It often roosts in large colonies and eats insects such as butterflies and moths. Because of its wide range, common occurrence, and tolerance of habitat degradation, it is not considered to be threatened                             </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:25%" valign= "top">
                        <ul id="newStuff" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">       
                            <li style="display: block;"><a href="/vA2BZNRrVf">2 column Google maps, foursquar..</a></li><hr class="line1">
                            <li style="display: block;"><a href="/ofJ48gWYEr">spsr..</a></li><hr class="line1">
                            <li style="display: block;"><a href="/9EwS0981bU">Bootstrap 3 Control Panel..</a></li><hr class="line1">
                            <li style="display: block;"><a href="/bs7VAhkjwy">twests..</a></li><hr class="line1">
                            <li style="display: block;"><a href="/MPMXbdIm9t">Interdev..</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>                           
                </tr>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to the scarecrow's answer,

You can use Chrome Developer tools (even IE/Firefox has the same options) to see what is happening with your layout, for yourself

1. Open your web page in Chrome Browser
2. Press   <kbd>F12</kbd>
3. Select Magnifying glass on Chrome developer tools window Top Left corner
4. Hover/Select the element you need to inspect.

Then check the right side panel of the Developer tools window, you can see what are the styles applied to the selected element (Styles tab), and what are the final values applied to the object (Computed tab) + more

Comment: I have not edited any bootstrap element. I just taken class as it is. so i dont know how can it response in this way

Answer (score 0):

1. You have set `margin` as 2% and it is working as intended. Double check with firebug to see the margin.
2. The space between `.well` and `.page-header` is because of the default css of those elements. This is the original css of page-header. See the margin property
   `.page-header
   {
       padding-bottom: 9px;
       margin: 40px 0 20px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
   }`
3. Same is the reason for `hr`. This is the original css 
   `hr {
       margin-top: 20px;
       margin-bottom: 20px;
       border: 0;
       border-top: 1px solid #eee;
   }`
4. Yes you can. Just apply the `border-color: #27ae60` style to an element that encloses all the other elements or the `body` element

Comment: thanks dude. I have not used `px` any where in my code. neither I want to use. I want to keep it responsive for all device. can you please update my fiddle

Comment: You can always customize the css of the core bootstrap elements if they are going to be the same for all over your application. Say, if you wish `hr` not to have 20px margin( which is the default behaviour) all over your app, create your own class for that or change default bootstrap.css to the way you want. That would do!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first of all, use development tools
From using it, i have some answers for you

1) if you talk about `.container` , do not use `margin` and `width` at the same time ... use only `margin` and let the width to expand the whole page (default `div`)

2) the `.page-header`  has inside a `h1`, which has its own top-bottom margins

3) same as for 2)

```
4) body {border-color: #27ae60}
```